# "android: can't find sdkmanager.jar"

Tags: android, path

I downloaded the Android SDK tools from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html which gave me a zip file called `tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip`. Unziped, it produced a folder called `tools`, containing the sdkmanager, `android`. When I tried to run it, it failed with the error message above.

I set `ANDROID_HOME` to the `tools` directory, but it still failed.

Answer (score 17):

It turns out that `ANDROID_HOME` needs to be set to the *parent* directory, with the contents of the zip file (a single directory named  `tools`) contained within it. Once I did that, it worked fine. This seemed confusing enough to be worth adding to stackoverflow.

Comment: I requested an improvement of this largely unhelpful error message at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230705.

Comment: Confirming that this worked for me; I created ~/Android and put the tools directory in side that. Now the PATH setup is:

export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android

export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH

Comment: It turns out that ANDROID_HOME is not really necessary. Renaming `tools` to `android-tools` really was the culprit.

Comment: They are separate issues, yes, but I ended up with both problems.

Answer (score 4):

The zip file can be opened anywhere.  The important thing is to leave the name "tools" and it's files intact.

Run the **android** program from the **tools** parent directory as:

```
$ ./tools/android
```

This will update the tools parent directory (the one from where you are running `./tools/android`) with a number of folders and tools.

I name this parent directory **sdk**.  I also place the whole directory (named `sdk`) in a folder by the name of the downloaded version.

Now for consistency of my programming environment I **bind mount** this **sdk** to a folder in the `/opt` directory so that it'll be available system-wide.

The hierarchy becomes:

```
/home/userid/android_r25.2.3/sdk
```

Now I make a folder in the `/opt/` directory called `/opt/android/sdk`.

My `/etc/fstab` entry for this becomes:

```
/home/userid/android_r25.2.3/sdk  /opt/android/sdk none bind
```

It's mounted with:

```
$ sudo mount /opt/android/sdk
```

The only thing that changes with new versions or new installs is the location of where the zip file is opened.  replace the **/home/userid/android_r25.2.3/sdk** with where you extract the zipfile and nothing else would ever have to be changed.

The PATH variable will consistently become:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android/sdk/tools:/opt/android/sdk/platform-tools
```

And, of course, the eclipse android configuration becomes:

```
/opt/android/sdk
```

Using this as a consistent procedure makes reinstalls and installs on new machines very seamless... having only one variable that might change, and that is where the package is extracted.

Answer (score 3):

One more issue is that one has to leave the name of the `unzip` result `tools` untouched and move it into a to be created directory in order to allow any version management (or leave it in your home directory if a information-free directory name like "tools" doesn't distrub you). Then set `ANDROID_HOME` like @JesseW explained.

Comment: Note that if you leave it in your home directory, and update the sdk, you will get additional directories created in your home directory, which you probably don't want.

Answer (score 0):

unzip tools into e.g. `~/android-sdk`, so it will live at `~/android-sdk/tools`

then in `~/.bashrc`

`export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/android-sdk"
ANDROID_TOOLS="$ANDROID_HOME/tools"
ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_TOOLS:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS;`

then run `sdkmanager`